# Django 1.6.5 test failing before executing tests

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.6

I am having an issue with Django 1.6.5 tests failing before it even starts to execute.

If I run `python manage.py test` it fails with the below message:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: (1007, "Can't create database 'test_marks_project'; database exists")
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_marks_project', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 50, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 71, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/test.py", line 8, in handle
    super(Command, self).handle(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 88, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 145, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 107, in setup_databases
    return setup_databases(self.verbosity, self.interactive, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 279, in setup_databases
    verbosity, autoclobber=not interactive)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 339, in create_test_db
    load_initial_data=False)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 159, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 112, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 216, in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 185, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 101, in create_permissions
    auth_app.Permission.objects.using(db).bulk_create(perms)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 359, in bulk_create
    self._batched_insert(objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 838, in _batched_insert
    using=self.db)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 232, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1514, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 903, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 207, in execute
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 117, in _warning_check
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: Data truncated for column 'name' at row 356

Warning: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'python manage.py test'
```

So far I've been unable to figure out what is causing this and how to solve it. I know that our database can only support index's of 191 chars or less, not sure if this is something to do with it.

**Edit**
I am using `UTF8MB4` encoding on the database (to support Emoji's etc...). This means my unique fields are limited to 191 and not 255. Not sure if this could be related.

Comment: Are you sure it finished deleting the old database?

Comment: What permissions do you have?
Can you show `perms` from:
    File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site- packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 101, in create_permissions

    auth_app.Permission.objects.using(db).bulk_create(perms)

Comment: Hey @limelights, I just manually deleted the test DB and had the same issue.

Comment: @zymud this is what the permissions looks like https://gist.github.com/markwint/29ff07b188bdd924b2dd.  I don't think it's related to permissions.

Comment: @Mark Winterbottom I need values of permissions names, not code for permissions.

You can add `print perms` before line `"/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 101` or use breakpoint to get perms values

Comment: @zymud sorry I'm not familiar with this, I tried to run 'print perms <url>' on linux but it says `Warning: unknown mime-type for "permis" -- using "application/octet-stream"`/ Is it the same as the unix  permissions? https://gist.github.com/markwint/a889d149ccd599872dcf. appreciate your help.

Comment: @Mark Winterbottom you are doing something wrong. I need value of Python variable `perms`, which django uses to create permissions. 
Just add to `print perms` line  to `/home/mark/.virtualenvs/marks_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py` before line 101, execute tests again and show me what print says

Comment: @zymud I apologize. I see what you mean now. I added code before line 101 to print the contents of the `perms` var. It's a bit long: https://gist.github.com/markwint/8126d5f09c6bba2f75f6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69683/discussion-between-mark-winterbottom-and-zymud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_length` of django `Permission.name` is 50:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6c1/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L71

And you have permission with name `'Can delete event participant check in location stats user'` which length is 57. Thats why django crashes.

I think you can change name of your permissions.

Comment: This was fixed only in django 1.8:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8a1/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L65